# Phantom space in glossary

Tags: spacing, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm trying to set up a newAbbreviationstyle with glossaries-extra, but have a phantom space I can't figure out.

Trying to make it so that the long name is automatically italicised for german-language abbreviations but not for english-language.

When I printglossary an extra space is added before the short name making the german-language abbreviations offset. see mwe.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc=true, section=chapter, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviationstyle{long-short-user-em}{
    %\GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{long-short-user}
    \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
        name={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
        sort={\the\glsshorttok},
        first={\protect\glsfirstlongemfont{\the\glslongtok}%
            \protect\glsxtruserparen{\protect\glsfirstabbrvuserfont{\the\glsshorttok}}%
            {\the\glslabeltok}},%
        firstplural={\protect\glsfirstlongemfont{\the\glslongpltok}%    
            \protect\glsxtruserparen
            {\protect\glsfirstabbrvuserfont{\the\glsshortpltok}}{\the\glslabeltok}},%
        plural={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},%
        description={\protect\glslongfont{\the\glslongtok}}
    }%
}{
    \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short-user}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsfirstlongfont}[1]{\glsfirstlongemfont{##1}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glslongfont}[1]{\glslongemfont{##1}}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-user}
\setabbreviationstyle[german]{long-short-user-em}
\setabbreviationstyle[english]{long-short-user}

\newabbreviation{DTA}{DTA}{Some acronym long}
\newabbreviation{DTB}{DTB}{some other acronym long}
\newabbreviation{DTF}{DTF}{blah foo blah}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{aaa}{AAA}{Some Italicised german word}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{bbb}{BBB}{Some other Italicised german word}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{ccc}{CCC}{Foo Foo Foo}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

[image]

sharelatex link: https://www.sharelatex.com/read/zdfmqjnmkrkv

*As a quick fix i'm manually setting emphasis in \newabbreviation call e.g. {ccc}{CCC}{\textit{Foo Foo Foo}} but looking for more elegant solution*

Comment: I spot a missing `%` in the line before `\GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts` and one in the `\newabbreviationstyle` line

Comment: I feel like an idiot considering how long i worked trying to track that down. But your solution worked. it was just a missing %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the missing `%` at the `}{` line; I've made some other reformatting for better showing the various levels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc=true, section=chapter, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviationstyle{long-short-user-em}{% <-- not really necessary
  %\GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{long-short-user}
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    sort={\the\glsshorttok},
    first={%
      \protect\glsfirstlongemfont{\the\glslongtok}%
      \protect\glsxtruserparen{\protect\glsfirstabbrvuserfont{\the\glsshorttok}}%
      {\the\glslabeltok}%
    },
    firstplural={%
      \protect\glsfirstlongemfont{\the\glslongpltok}%    
      \protect\glsxtruserparen{%
        \protect\glsfirstabbrvuserfont{\the\glsshortpltok}%
      }{\the\glslabeltok}
    },
    plural={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},
    description={\protect\glslongfont{\the\glslongtok}},
  }%
}{% <-- this was the missing one
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short-user}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsfirstlongfont}[1]{\glsfirstlongemfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glslongfont}[1]{\glslongemfont{##1}}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-user}
\setabbreviationstyle[german]{long-short-user-em}
\setabbreviationstyle[english]{long-short-user}

\newabbreviation{DTA}{DTA}{Some acronym long}
\newabbreviation{DTB}{DTB}{some other acronym long}
\newabbreviation{DTF}{DTF}{blah foo blah}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{aaa}{AAA}{Some Italicised german word}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{bbb}{BBB}{Some other Italicised german word}
\newabbreviation[category=german]{ccc}{CCC}{Foo Foo Foo}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. Not sure why that % should be necessary though. Can you explain?